# How can I get the text of a JavaScript-generated input element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table that creates a row of input elements each time the "+" button is clicked underneath it. All elements are given the className "table-data". Once the "Done" button is clicked I want to loop through all these elements and get the text inside of them:

```html
<table id="myTable"></table>

<button onclick="addRow();">+</button>
<button onclick="getData();">Done</button>
```

```js
function addRow() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);

    cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    cell1.innerHTML = '<input type="text"></input>';
    cell1.className = 'table-data';

    cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell2.innerHTML = '<input type="text"></input>'; 
    cell2.className = 'table-data';
}


function getData() {
    inputCells = document.getElementsByClassName("table-data");

    for (var i = 0; i < inputCells.length(); i++) {
        console.log(inputCells[i].innerHTML);
}
}
```

However, when I run this code it just logs: 'input type="text"'

I tried using this instead:

```js
console.log(inputCells[i].value);
```

But this method just logs "undefined". How can I get the value of these input elements?

Note: I don't mind if jQuery is used to answer this question.

Comment: `.getElementById()` is for finding elements by their **id** attribute values; you're giving your elements a `class`. You're looking for `.getElementsByClassName()`.

Comment: @Pointy Sorry about that, I wrote that part manually rather than copying and pasting from my real code. That mistake isn't in my real code file, so it doesn't have to do with the results I am getting.

Comment: If you've posted incorrect code then you might be best to update it?

Comment: @Steve I am new to this site, can you tell me how to edit my post?

Comment: There should be an edit button at the bottom of your post.

Comment: @Steve thanks I got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've prepared a solution for you using jQuery as your question is tagged with it. My solution find all inputs in table and then iterates over them using [jQuery#each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method.

```js
const $table = $('#myTable');

$('#addBtn').on('click', function() {
  let tr = $('<tr>');
  let td1 = $('<td>');
  let td2 = $('<td>');
  let input = $('<input>', {
    type: 'text',
    class: 'table-data'
  });

  td1.append(input.clone());
  td2.append(input.clone());

  tr.append(td1);
  tr.append(td2);
  $table.append(tr);
});

$('#doneBtn').on('click', function() {
  $table.find('input').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable"></table>

<button id='addBtn'>+</button>
<button id='doneBtn'>Done</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Details commented in demo

```js
// Reference form
const form = document.forms[0];

/*
//A Pass a number (max 10)
//B Reference table
//C Number of cells in a row
//D if number of cells in a row is less than input number...
//E Run addCols() function
//F Number of cells in a row is equal to number of the input
//G Add row
//H On each iteration...
//I Add a cell
//J Create an input assign type and name
//K Add input to cell.
*/
function addRow(count) {//A
  const table = document.querySelector("table");//B
  let width = table.rows[0].cells.length;//C
  if (width < count) {//D
    addCols(table, width, count);//E
    width = count;//F
  }
  const row = table.insertRow();//G
  for (let r = 0; r < width; r++) {//H
    const cell = row.insertCell();//I
    const text = document.createElement('input');//J
    text.name = 'data';
    text.type = 'text';
    cell.appendChild(text);//K
  }
  return false;
}

// Similar to addRow() but will only adds cells 
function addCols(table, width, count) {
  let rowCount = table.rows.length;
  for (let r = 0; r < rowCount; r++) {
    let row = table.rows[r];
    for (let c = 0; c < (count - width); c++) {
      let cell = row.insertCell();
      let text = document.createElement('input');
      text.type = 'text';
      text.name = 'data';
      cell.appendChild(text);
    }
  }
  return false;
}

/*
//A Pass Event Object
//B Prevent the form from sending data to a browser
//C Collect all form controls and convert collection into array
//D Use flatMap() to filter in the inputs with text and extract it
*/
function getData(event) {//A
  event.preventDefault();//B
  const ui = [...this.elements];//C
  let txt = ui.flatMap(field => field.matches('[name=data]') && field.value !== '' ? [field.value] : []);//D
  console.log(txt);
  return txt;
}

//Register the button to click event
form.elements.add.onclick = function(event) {
  const qty = Number(event.target.previousElementSibling.value);
  addRow(qty);
};

//Register the form to submit event
form.onsubmit = getData;
```

```css
input {display:inline-block;font:inherit;width:10vw}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id='qty' type='number' min='0' max='10' value='2'>
  <button id='add' type='button'>+</button>
  <button type='submit'>Done</button>
  <table><tr></tr></table>
</form>
```